# What is the formula for the derived sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[what the sequence is derived from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEmAY.png%5C)

Once the sequence is derived how is that turned into a formula and what is it?
Ive been working on this for hours im not getting anywhere. Very thankful to anyone answering my maths problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: And tell us how you tried to address the question during these hours.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$b_{n+1}-b_{n}=n-2\tag 1$$
$$b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}=n+1-2\tag 2$$

$$(2)-(1)= ???$$

Answer (score 0):

The difference of two successive $b$'s is a linear polynomial so you can expect that a $b$ follows a quadratic polynomial, because $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$ (quadratic yields linear).

We set

$$b_n=pn^2+qn+r$$

and solve

$$b_{n+1}-b_n=p(2n+1)+q=n-2$$ and by identification

> $$p=\frac12,\\q=-\frac{5}2.$$

Hence

> $$b_n=\frac{n^2-5n}2+r$$ where $r$ is free.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at this for a while it half makes sense. I just started a discreet math unit, I don't know much math past Australian high school math. what does r mean? where did p and q come from?

Comment: @SchoolEmail672: this is said in my answer.